# Simple inbuilt way to Create or Delete and Create A directory

Tags: powershell

In powershell scripts is there a single inbuilt way to recreate a directory, I tend to use this over and over in a lot of different scripts, while it does the job, it causes clutter, I can make a function, but I'd end up copy pasting it a lot, just wondering if there is a more straightforward way to do this.

```
If(Test-path $destination) 
{
   Remove-item $destination -Force -Recurse
}
New-Item $destination -type directory
```

Comment: I don't understand how creating your own function (which you can then put in your `$profile` or a module you use in all your scripts) would be more "messy" than a built-in function to do the same task (which there is not).

Comment: because, the scripts get used on many different machines where I don't want the problem of having to set up common scripts in many places

Comment: Why can't you distribute the module/common scripts the same way you distribute the rest of your scripts?

Comment: I looked into `New-Item`'s `-force` parameter, but sadly, it does not empty folders of their contents, so it effectively does nothing. I don't think there is an easier way to do this. Perhaps you could find a way to package this function so that you can import it whenever you need it?

Comment: @alroc  many of the scripts are part of other systems that trigger on various events, some machines are transient virtual machines, there's not one common way to get the scripts in each environment

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to delete and create a directory in a single command in Powershell. Unless resorting to the mentioned function or module approach, it'll be 2 lines minimum.

You could achieve the same with:

```
Remove-item $destination -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
New-Item $destination -type directory
```

Making it an inline function:

```
Function RecreateDirectory( [string]$destination ) {
    Remove-item $destination -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    New-Item $destination -type directory
}

RecreateDirectory("C:\OneDir")
RecreateDirectory("C:\AnotherDir")
```